# Error: Unable to parse JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 540

Tags: json, firebase, syntax-error

I'm trying to deploy a project with firebase init. When I get to the part that asks me this: "What file should be used for Realtime Database Security Rules? database.rules.json", I press enter and an error appears:

**Error: Unable to parse JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 540**

how can i solve this?

Comment: I don't know Firebase, but there seems to be a syntax error in the JSON file. I'd suggest you open that database.rules.json in an IDE, which will most likely show you where the error is, which you can probably fix by deleting the `}` or moving it somewhere else.

Comment: Please post your JSON here and anonymize any sensitive information before posting